# How to download a file using boost asio?

Tags: android, c++, boost, boost-asio, embedded-linux

I am working on android for now and I searched through the net for downloading a file using boost but I couldn't find any robust simple example for usage. Can you give me an example of downloading a text file from net using boost.asio or can you suggest an reliable TCP/IP communication framework for doing this?

Why I am asking this question is because I tried these cases:

- cpp-netlib (Gives endian error when compiling for arm-linux-androideabi toolchain, g++ as a linker)
- curl (requires libz and if I compile libz static it gives segfault on running)

I am using the patched version of boost in here: https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

Comment: Boost.Asio does not directly provide this functionality.  However, one could implement a higher level protocol, such as HTTP, using Boost.Asio.  It may be worth considering [urdl](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/urdl), from Boost.Asio's author, designed to be a cross-platform C++ library for downloading web content using a URL.